# Securing Local Development Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

Has anyone tried to restrict their local development server in Ruby on Rails?

I'm working on a project in development on my PC, and wondered if there was a way to restrict this so only localhost (my machine) can make requests.

At the moment anybody on the network can navigate to my machine and access my application while I'm running in development. This is a very basic out of the box installation of RoR.

Comment: You don't trust your coworkers? Why do you need to secure it? If you have concerns, tell your management to tell everyone to keep off your box.

Comment: It was more to practice good security while developing.

Comment: In an in-house environment, it should be well known to respect the work environments of others. If you can't expect that then, yes, immediately enable basic-authentication, and start looking for a job somewhere more mature.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's not a corporate it's my own network.

Comment: Ah. Turn on your firewall and nobody can see it unless you give them access. Set the server to sit on 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 so only you can see it like @mosch said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bundle exec rails server -b 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 was implemented to allow this sort of situation - inside the host access only.

Answer (score 1):

From a networking perspective the best way would be to secure your iptables.

From the rails side of the house you could just use [basic auth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) or something like devise. Or utilize the  [request object](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects) with a before filter and whitelist your machine.

Good luck!

Comment: I like the idea of adding basic auth, my application doesn't really need any kind of authentication but I'd like to be the only one to access. Binding to an address and adding basic auth would is my belt and braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
before_filter :restrict_access
def restrict_access
  return unless config_option(:allowed_IPs)
  if not config_option(:allowed_IPs).include?(request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    render :file => "#{Rails.public_path}/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
    return
  end
end
```

and

```
(/config/site_config.yml):
development:
production:
  allowed_IPs:
    - IP1
    - IP2
    # etc.
```

With the help of [this post](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=89791#p89791)

Comment: Thanks this is great reference for the future.